# There's named parameters, and then there's

Tags: language-agnostic, parameters

Since named parameters are those parameters that are identified by their explicit name, instead of their ordering, what's the name of their cousins without names, the ones that are identified merely by the order?

Anonymous parameters? Unnamed parameters? Do they have a name to begin with?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

positional parameters.

If you google "positional parameters", you'll usually find it referring to the $1, $2, $3 variables you get in shell scripting, but it works for "normal" parameters as well.

Comment: Seems like C# uses this term: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664614%28VS.71%29.aspx?ppud=4

Answer (score 5):

Parameters.

Comment: They don't have a name, because they don't have a name.  It makes sense!

Comment: Hm, I was hoping for something that would distinctly set them apart. Saying "there's named parameters and parameters" sounds confusing :/

Answer (score 1):

In Python, there are *keyword arguments* and *arguments*.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the tutorial, kinda.

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

> In general, an argument list must have
> any positional arguments followed by
> any keyword arguments, where the
> keywords must be chosen from the
> formal parameter names.

And the glossary:

http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#glossary

> argument
>
> A value passed to a function or method, assigned to a named local
> variable in the function body. A
> function or method may have both
> positional arguments and keyword
> arguments in its definition.
>
> positional argument
>
> The arguments assigned to local names
> inside a function or method,
> determined by the order in which they
> were given in the call. * is used to
> either accept multiple positional
> arguments (when in the definition), or
> pass several arguments as a list to a
> function. See argument.